# A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: Social::$social_model Filename: controllers/social.php Line Number: 10

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

while running the codeigniter I have a following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Notice Message: Undefined property: Social::$social_model Filename: controllers/social.php Line Number: 10

Whats wrong with my code any help please?

`controllers/social.php`

```
class Social extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){

            $data = array();
            $this->load->view('header.php');
            $this->load->view('staffs/content.php');
            if ($query = $this-> social_model -> get_records()) // **[line 10]**
            {
                $data['records'] = $query;
            }

            $this->load->view('social/content.php', $data); 
            $this->load->view('footer.php');
        }

   // ....
}
```

`models/social_model.php`

```
<?php
class  social_model extends CI_Model{

    function get_records()
    {
        $query = $this->db->get('admins');
        return $query -> result();
    }

   // ....
}
```

Comment: Should be `if ($query == $this`?

Comment: i tried it but it also didnt work :(

Comment: Your code doesn't show any relationship between Social and site_model. In fact, you refer to it as social_model in Social, but you never instantiate anything as $this->social_model. If you don't declare the parameter social_model, then you can't use it.

Comment: i am sory its actually a social_model, sorry for the spelling misplaced during the post, its social_model and its also didnt work.

Comment: Aren't u missing: $this->load->model('Social_model.php'); (I dont remember the exact syntax) before calling $this->social_model?

Comment: Wow Jorge. thank you so much, that was a minor code but i forget to write, Any way yo solved my problem thak you so so much...

Answer (score 1):

You must load model:

```
$this->load->model('social_model');
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. While this solves the OP's problem, a good answer is more than that. Describe the cause of the notice mentioned in the question, explain how the code change you suggest fixes the problem.